# I am not able to pass dynamic data in html file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to render my database information into HTML pages. I have used the way of passing dynamic data from databases. But, it's not working. I am seeing an empty page as a result.

models.py

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    business_services = models.CharField(max_length =50)
    business_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    business_description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.business_name
```

views.py

```
def get_data(request):
    business = Business.objects.all()
    b = {'business': business}
    return render(request, "test.html", b)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', get_data),

    ]
```

test.html

```
{{ business.business_name }}
{{ business.services }}
```

Comment: it is error free.

Comment: `business` is a queryset, not a `Business` object. You need to loop over it in the template.

Comment: I am not being able to get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`business` is the instance of class `Business`. So, in test.html, do the following:

```
{% for b in business %}
    {{ b.business_name }}
    {{ b.services }}
{% endfor %}
```